# How can I select and group comparative and superlative words from a text file?

Tags: python, nlp, nodebox-linguistics

I am trying to filter the words in a text file. If there are any 'comparative' and 'superlative' words in the file, I want to convert them  to 'positive'.

e.g. - 'greatest' -> 'great' and so on.

I am using 'pattern' module for this. In example it says,

```
from pattern.en import comparative, superlative
print comparative('bad')
```

gives -> `worse` works fine. 
but, If I do:

```
from pattern.en import comparative, superlative, positive
print positive('worse')
```

It gives, `'False'`

Am I doing it wrong ? Is there any way to find out 'comparative' and 'superlative' words and print the positive word of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding: the `positive()` function doesn't do what you think.

As far as I can see, the `pattern.en` module only provides functions for generating comparatives and superlatives from the positive form of an adjective, but not for the inverse (analysing the forms as comparative/superlative of a positive form).
There is a `lemma()` function, which you could expect to do this, but unfortunately it only works for verbs.

The `positive()` function you found belongs to sentiment detection; it tries to tell if a given sentence has a positive polarity.

So, what do you do now?
I see two possibilities: You either switch to a different library which supports lemmatisation of adjectives (eg. SpaCy), or you try to build a simple adjective lemmatiser based on the code from the `pattern.en` module.

If you go for the second option, have a look at the last 80 lines of code in the [`inflect` module](https://github.com/clips/pattern/blob/master/pattern/text/en/inflect.py). I suggest you first try to catch the irregular cases (using an inversion of the table given there), then you strip off the `-er`/`-est` suffix. There's probably a number of special cases (like `i` → `y` in `heavier` → `heavy`).
Try something yourself, and if you run into problems come back here with a new question!